# Non-galois real extensions of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: rational-numbers, splitting-field, galois-extensions

$\newcommand\Q{\mathbb{Q}} \newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}} \newcommand\C{\mathbb{C}}$

Consider the condition:
$\alpha\in \R$ is an algebraic irrational real number and $\Q(\alpha)$ is not Galois (or normal) over $\Q$ and the splitting field, say $K$, of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\Q$ has non-real elements (in this case it is a totally imaginary field).

Now, is it true that for all $\alpha$ satisfying above there is a $\beta\in K\backslash\R$ such that $\textrm{Im}(\beta)^2 \in \Q(\alpha)$?

I think the above can be answered by knowing a little bit more about quadratic field extensions (than I do). Any ideas or counterexamples?

**Edit**: My feeling is that we get a counterexample if we look at some splitting field of $x^n-q$ for some positive rational ($\neq 1$). Let's say the splitting field of $x^3-2$, then any non-real element $\beta$ of this field will not have the described property. This wouldn't work for an even degree $n$ divisible by $4$. Because you just take the purely imaginary $g^{n/4}$, where $g$ is a primitive $n$-th root of $2$, as your $\beta$.

Comment: can you be more precise? $\beta=i$ works...

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Can you edit for clarity?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.

Comment: @DonAntonio why do you conclude from that that $a,b$ are in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @ArtW and lulu. I see where the problem was, I meant of course that $\beta$ is in the splitting field. I made the correction. I hope this is clear now

Comment: @quantum I messed a little the question, which wasn't clear enough, and thought it was a quadratic extension...which of course is absurd if the extension isn't normal. Deleting that comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio: $K$ is the splitting field of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. I only made *one* change since my first post (changed $\mathbb C$ to $K$ and introduced the symbol $K$).

Comment: You are tacitly assuming a fixed embedding of $K$ into $\Bbb{C}$ now. Anyway, the assertion is true if $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha) = K\cap \Bbb{R}$. Namely, let $\gamma = a+bi$ any non-real root of the min.pol. $f$ of $\alpha$ over $\Bbb{Q}$. Then, since $f$ has real coefficients, $\bar\gamma = a-bi \in K$, hence $\beta := \gamma -\bar\gamma = 2bi \in K \setminus \Bbb{R}$. Then $\beta =Im(\beta)$ and $\beta^2 \in K\cap \Bbb{R}$.

Comment: @Torsten: Agreed. Small correction: you meant $2b = {\rm Im}(\beta)$.